# How to create array of arraylist , with different types of objects in each arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to create an array of ArrayList objects.

Lets assume the array to be of size 3, so it holds 3 lists. The type of data stored in ArrayList at each index of array is different, like: ArrayList at index 0 contains objects of Class "student", ArrayList at index 1 contains objects of Class "Professor" and ArrayList at index 2 contains objects of Class "Parent".

How to create it?

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Use map instead of array. And store `arraylists` in map with key.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: @GhostCat how can i improve my question

Comment: You would start by writing code. This community is not a tutor service where people guide you through the learning process. You simply put down a bit of text with vague explanations. Seriously: step back, and start writing code. Then *first* work your peers, and maybe other real people around you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in safelly you can consider object of ArrayList. In detail create like this classes;

**Person.class**

```
public class Person{
    //common fields of person
}
```

**Student.class**

```
public class Student extends Person{
  //fields of Student
}
```

**Professeor.class**

```
public class Professor extends Person{
  //fields of Professor
}
```

**Parent.class**

```
public class Parent extends Person{
  //fields of Parent
}
```

Now you can create **Arrays of ArrayList** like this from generic class.This implementation is ;

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Person>> personList = new ArrayList<>();

//studentList is keeps instance of Person as student
ArrayList<Person> students = new ArrayList<>();
students.add(new Student());
personList.add(students);

//professorsList is keeps instance of Person as professor
ArrayList<Person> professors = new ArrayList<>();
students.add(new Professor());
personList.add(professors);

//parentList is keeps instance of Person as parents
ArrayList<Person> parents = new ArrayList<>();
students.add(new Parent());
personList.add(parents);
```

*For more reads:*[ArrayList](https://www.baeldung.com/java-arraylist)

Answer (score 0):

You can use not parametrized `ArrayList`

```
List<List> genericList = new ArrayList<List>();
genericList.add(*new ArrayList()*);
```

But it is not recommended as you will lose information about a type of each list. (and you have to cast it by yourself)

Answer (score 0):

That would look something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         ArrayList<ArrayList> arrs = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
         arrs.add(new ArrayList<String>());
         arrs.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
         arrs.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
         ((ArrayList<String>)arrs.get(0)).add("Hello World!");
        System.out.println(arrs.get(0).get(0));
     }
}
```

This is not entirely safe to do since you will have to cast the ArrayList with the generic type that you are expecting in each retrieval from the parent ArrayList.